# Secure class construction

Tags: php, sql, security, oop, xss

Is it secure to call `__construct()` in login or sign up class this way:

```
function __construct(PDO $DBH, $_POST['1'], $_POST['2'])
{
    $this->_user=$_POST['1'];
    $this->_pass=$_POST['2'];
    $this->_DBH=$DBH;
}
```

I want to sanitize user input later inside this class and I'm not sure would my code be ripe for SQL injection or XSS because of class costructed with raw POST input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know you sanitize/use prepared statements (i.e. the raw POST data is not inserted as is to the query), it's fine to do so.

In fact, if you use prepared statements, you don't need to sanitize your input at all (for SQL, if you're going to display the data as HTML, it still needs to be sanitized as such).

Comment: I'm going to use `htmlentities()` and PDO `bindParam`. Will it be good?

Comment: @riwette No. Don't escape or encode data you pass to a prepared statement because PDO takes care of the necessary escaping on its own (your database doesn't contain strings in HTML entity encoding, does it?). Further, see [Why Can't I Just HTML Entity Encode Untrusted Data?](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F) regarding the pitfals of simply using `htmlentities()` for XSS mitigation. It's generally not enough.

Comment: @user113215: It's (sadly) not uncommon for users to store HTML strings in databases, hence I suggest he does sanitize for HTML if he uses it.

Answer (score 4):

Copying non-sanitized data from one variable into another variable isn't going to make a difference; this is not what SQL injection / XSS is about.

It's about applying appropriate escaping (or rather, avoid no escaping) when those variables are *being used*. Your risk of SQL injection are greatly mitigated by simply using prepared statements; escaping output to prevent XSS is still necessary though :)

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea not to parse user input. Whenever a user inputs something you should  check the input.

Answer (score 1):

I always `htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);`, just to be on the safe side.

Use prepared statements, and never trust user input.

Comment: Careful. This is generally insufficient to prevent XSS. See [Why Can't I Just HTML Entity Encode Untrusted Data?](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't where you should be worried about injection attacks. SQL injection prevention generally amounts of sanitizing **inputs**; XSS prevention generally amounts to various forms of **output** encoding. Neither of these is necessarily related to the internal representation of your data (the value of the variable itself).

As others have mentioned, the use of prepared statements  ([PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)) will perform the necessary SQL injection escaping automatically. Ultimately, though, because [the appropriate transformation varies based on how you're using the data](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F), **you should generally do this mitigation at the time of use**.